# Getting data out of deserialized object classes in C# using json.net

Tags: c#, json, implicit

This class I created myself:

```
    public class member
{
    public string account_name { get; set; }
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public Rootobject[] rootobject { get; set; }
}
```

This are the classes VS created for me autmatically using an example JSON answer:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class Meta
{
    public int count { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public _507888780[] _507888780 { get; set; }
}
public class _507888780
{
    public All all { get; set; }
    public int tank_id { get; set; }
}
public class All
{
    public int spotted { get; set; }
    public int hits_percents { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

A small part of the JSON response from the API server I use looks like this:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"meta": {
    "count": 1
},
"data": {
    "507888780": [
        {
            "all": {
                "spotted": 467,
                "hits_percents": 83,
                "wins": 281,
            },
            "tank_id": 2849
        },
        {
            "all": {
                "spotted": 224,
                "hits_percents": 63,
                "wins": 32,
            },
            "tank_id": 9473
        },
        }
```

}

This is the code I use to read out the tanks a member has (including all the stats) where Request(string) is just the http request.

```
private List<member> memberlist = new List<member>(100);
private void DoStuff()
{
memberlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<member>>(result_member);
foreach (var member in memberlist)
        {
            string result_tank = Request("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/tanks/stats/?application_id=" + application_id + "&account_id=" + member.account_id + "&tank_id=" + tanks + "&fields=all.battles%2C+all.wins%2C+all.damage_dealt%2C+all.frags%2C+all.hits_percents%2C+all.piercings%2C+all.shots%2C+all.spotted%2C+all.survived_battles%2C+all.tanking_factor");
            var Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result_tank);
            foreach (var tank in _507888780)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += Rootobject.data._507888780[tank].tank_id + Rootobject.data._507888780[tank].all.spotted.ToString() + "...";
            }
        }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to search up all the different tanks including their stats for all members. Right now I'm getting the error in the line I want to print "Type Tank_Statistics._507888780 cannot be implicitly converted to int." Earlier on I alos got an error with a missing IEnumerable which I dont have right now though..
Anyways .. I can't make it work somehow.. it would be very kind if someone would be able to help me on this ;)

Comment: Please show [MCVE] of the problem, not code that constructs objects or JSON (neither are directly related to problem you have).

Comment: Also, please submit it to [.NETFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) and share it here

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Ix4pL
Thats with the suggested change of @tym32167
Now I do have the problem that 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject doesnt seem to populate the classes correctly.

Comment: I guess thats because the JSON object is just a number, but the class is _number.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you should replace this

```
 richTextBox1.Text += Rootobject.data._507888780[tank].tank_id + Rootobject.data._507888780[tank].all.spotted.ToString() + "...";
```

to this

```
richTextBox1.Text += tank.tank_id + tank.all.spotted.ToString() + "...";
```

Comment: thanks, now that solved this problem ;)
now I realized that the Deserialize is not populating the _507888780 class somehow.. trying to call anything in that class will always return null.